# How to make VSCode play nice with React syntax?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I installed all recommended extensions, still VSCode won't recognize any React syntax.

What must i do to make **VSCode** play nice with **React (js / jsx) syntax?**

[image]

Comment: Which version do you use? I do not have installed any JSX plugins and everything works fine. Maybe the JSX plugin you're using breaks the support?

Comment: Should be latest version 1.10.2. I uninstalled the extensions and it's the same thing.

Comment: When I tried it I didn't insert alle the white spaces you have. Is there a reason to do this? I think spaces between `<` and `/` are not allowed, see the spec: https://github.com/fxbois/jsx

Comment: As it turns out, this seems to be a bug in TypeScript's understanding of JSX (vscode uses the TS service in the background to show you errors in your JS code). Compiling your example works fine though. There is no run time error.

Comment: Yes, it works, that is true, but it's impossible to work like that Q_Q

Comment: @SebastianSebald "I think spaces between < and / are not allowed". This turned out to be my issue, i think because of the beautify plugin. I removed the plugin and the spacings and the red squigglys are gone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VS Code has built-in support for JSX and TSX. You do not need to install any extensions unless you want additional functionality

As the OP noted, the problem was one of their extensions was inserting spaces around the tags. I suspect it was the `js css html formatter` extensions since this has caused problem for people in the past

Answer (score 5):

The plugin that was causing issues for me here actually Babel ES6/ES7 as mentioned in another comment.

Once removing that plugin and reloading, it all worked well

Comment: You save my day, thanks, man. Love you

Answer (score 0):

1.Delete all html-js-css formatters.
2.If you want to work with this formatters,
install prettier.
Right click and select format document with and then select prettier. Repeat this every saving.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you use some HTML formatter, so first go to your react native or js extension settings(simple click the bottom bar language mod), and check the HTML fomatter in that setting page.

```
"[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "apility.beautify-blade"
}
```

remove this, and you are good to go.

Answer (score -1):

Afaik, vscode does not understand JSX by default. Installing [jsx](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TwentyChung.jsx) plugin should help there.

Comment: Check out the picture. It's installed, allong with React Native Tools, Reactjs code snippets and React-Beautify, but they don't make any difference it seems. I'm interested not only for jsx, but also for js files that contain React syntax.

Comment: VSCode has builtin support for JSX. Many of the jsx extensions actually mess things up more

Answer (score -1):

Install Babel ES6/ES7 extension from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dzannotti.vscode-babel-coloring).

Works like charm.

[image]